# Cordova Backbone App - Ajax requests failing on specifically LG G4s + Samsung S7 w/ Wifi on

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova, backbone.js

**Issue**

I have an App built in backbone.js and Cordova. It is having issues making an Ajax request in a very niche situation - specifically this issue happens only on an LG G4 (and Samsung S7) with the Wifi On. It likely has issues on others but I've only tested 4 phone models so far. I am using jQuery to make an Ajax call.

What I mean by issues making an Ajax request is that the request actually fails. In my developer tools on the Network tab, the status shows (failed). If i console log the XHR.status it shows a 0.

If i console log the thrown error I get the following...

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://mywebsite.com/Unicorn/API/FooBar.svc/JSON/DoThisPlease?var1=whatisone&var2=morestuff&clientInfo=Android%20undefined%206.0'
```

**Code**

The code for my request is as follows...

```
function doSomeAjaxCall(successCallback, failureCallback) {
        var deviceInfo = getDeviceInfo();
        var request_url = baseUrl + "DoThisPlease?var1=" + encodeURIComponent(varA) + "&var2=" + encodeURIComponent(varB) + "&deviceInfo=" + encodeURIComponent(deviceInfo);
        $.ajax({
            url:request_url,
            async:false,
            success:function (json) {
                if (json === "") {
                    failureCallback("Invalid email and/or password");
                } else {
                    successCallback(json);
                }
            },
            error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (jqXHR.status === 404)
                    failureCallback('The API was not found at this URL');
                else if (jqXHR.status === 0)
                    failureCallback('Cannot connect to PD, make sure your device is online.');
                else
                  failureCallback('Server Responded with: ' + jqXHR.statusText);
            }
        });
    }
```

**Things I've Tried**

It should be noted that if I take the request url and paste it into a web browser it will also not work on Wifi.

This all being said, the minute I disable Wifi and data takes over everything works. I have tried the app in the following data settings:

- *Wifi* **On** *Data* **On** *Result* **Fails**
- *Wifi* **On** *Data* **Off** *Result* **Fails**
- *Wifi* **Off** *Data* **On** *Result* **Works**

Phones I've Tried

- Samsung S6 Android 6.0.1 *Works on all Data Configurations*
- LG G3 *Android 6.0 Works on all Data Configurations*
- Lg G4 Android 6.0 **FAILS (with Wifi On see above configurations)**
- Samsung S7 Android 6.0.1 **FAILS (with Wifi On see above configurations)**

Version of Chrome on all devices is 53.0.2785.124

I can't quite wrap my finger around why this issue is happening. Any feedback on this issue or debugging Cordova apps in general would be nice.

I am currently debugging using chrome's inspector over ADB with the phone plugged in to USB.

**EDIT 10/20**

As per @Gandhi's suggestion I tried hitting other APIs. I was able to hit an API on a different machine - I used the Federal Reserve Economic Data API. I tried hitting a different API on the SAME machine and it had the same errors as attempting to make an AJAX request to the original API did. I also did some testing on a Samsung Galaxy S7 and it's results are the same as the LG G4.

*Thought 1:* I have an IIS server and I am starting to wonder if there is some sort of configuration issue on new Android phones (models, not Android software version) or the IIS server that is causing this issue.

*Thought 2:* I am going to do some testing today and try getting out of the office with the phones and trying a Wifi connection on a different network. I wonder if the way network requests are made on certain phone models might interact differently with our network. I'm not much of an expert on the Android OS itself but I think phone model shouldn't matter as the OS (version of Android) would handle the requests (just using the phone model's hardware) and conform to some standard for the requests. Regardless I'm going to try this today and update with results.

Comment: A quick guess is that it's a weird issue with the phone and possibly nothing  related to backbone or cordova.

Comment: @Jake Going by your following lines - "It should be noted that if I take the request url and paste it into a web browser it will also not work on Wifi." i guess it should be an issue with your wifi. Did you test ajax calls to some other URL over wifi?

Comment: @Gandhi ,that was a good suggestion. I tried hitting a different API - just one from the fed's economic data - and managed to get a response regardless of Wifi configuration. I also tried hitting an API on the SAME server. This did not work. I have also been able to do some testing with another device, a Samsung S7, and the same issues occur as the G4.

Comment: UPDATE: I know it's a later update. We ended up nailing down the issues to specific Wifi connections. There wasn't any similarity between Wifi points that gave this issue, but it seems that it might be based upon security policies of different network setups. It's weird that it only affects our backbone cordova app and none of our other apps. Will choose an answer if we ever figure out the specific network configurations.